# Evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(r\pi x)}{r \cdot y^r}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> **Find a closed form expression for**
>
> $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(r\pi x)}{r \cdot y^r}$$

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(r \pi x)}{r} = \dfrac{\pi}{2} -  \left\{\dfrac{x}{2}\right \}$ but I don't know how to obtain a closed form for the required summation. I thought about using [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) but it became messy.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It may be useful to use a [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), between the sum you already know, and the "other part", which is a geometric series in $y$.

Comment: @Mark Can you please elaborate and post as answer?

Comment: Do we know something about $y$?

Comment: @Hetebrij $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Comment: But do you want all $y \neq 0$, $y$ postive, $y$ bigger than $1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(r\pi x)}{r \cdot y^r}=\mathrm{Im}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\exp(\mathrm{i}r\pi x)}{r \cdot y^r}=\mathrm{Im}\int_0^\infty ds \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}\pi x-s}}{y}\right)^r=\mathrm{Im}\int_0^\infty ds\frac{e^{i \pi  x}}{e^s y-e^{i \pi  x}}=
$$
$$
=-\mathrm{Im}\log \left(1-\frac{e^{i \pi  x}}{y}\right)=- \mathrm{arctan}\left(1-\frac{\cos (\pi  x)}{y},-\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{y}\right)\ ,
$$
where $\log$ is the principal branch of the complex logarithm, and we used $1/z=\int_0^\infty ds\ e^{-s z}$, for $z>0$. The function arctan with two arguments is described here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html. I checked with Mathematica a few cases and it seems it works.